# Why isn't my Salt minion showing any pillar attributes?

Tags: salt-stack, configuration-management

I've been through the [salt](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/walkthrough.html#tutorial-salt-walk-through) and [pillar](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/pillar.html) walkthroughs and in general, everything works as expected with my setup.  In fact, there isn't anything that I'm aware of that isn't working properly...until now.

This is my first foray into using the pillar system.  I have access keys that I am trying to protect so I'd like for pillar to allow me to keep tabs on which minions get copies of them.

Here is my setup.

Directory structure:

```
[root@master config-mgmt]# tree /srv/pillar
/srv/pillar
├── awscreds.sls
├── data.sls
├── dev
└── top.sls
```

`/srv/pillar/top.sls` file:

```
[root@master config-mgmt]# cat /srv/pillar/top.sls
dev:
  'roles:*aws*':
    - match: grain
    - awscreds
  '*':
    - data
```

Eventually, I'd like to be able to match on my "roles" grain but for this test, to keep things simple, I am only concerned with the glob match (`'*'`).

For all minions, it ought to run the `data` state, which is here:

```
[root@master config-mgmt]# cat /srv/pillar/data.sls
info: some data for poc
```

From my salt-master, I run `refresh_pillar`:

```
[root@master config-mgmt]# salt '*salttest*' saltutil.refresh_pillar
slave-salttesting-01.eng.example.com:
True
```

Seems okay.  But, neither on the minion nor the master are the pillar attributes present in any form.

On the master:

```
[root@master config-mgmt]# salt '*salttest*' pillar.ls
slave-salttesting-01.eng.example.com:
```

On the minion:

```
[root@slave-salttesting-01 ~]# salt-call pillar.ls
local:
```

I'm running a recent version of salt:

```
[root@master config-mgmt]# salt --version
salt 2018.3.3 (Oxygen)
```

Any ideas why my minion isn't picking up any attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.  I wasn't familiar with the `/etc/salt/master` file until my colleague suggested that I check it.  The `salt_pillar` section had a typo for `dev` (defined as `/sr/salt/dev` and not `/srv/salt/dev` and `base` was defined as pointing to a location other than the default.  I made sure that `base` was set to `/srv/salt` and `dev` was set to `/srv/salt/dev`.  I then had to go back into `/srv/salt` and make sure that `top.sls` was in the `/srv/salt` location.  I also moved `data.sls` and `awscreds.sls` to `/srv/salt/dev` because I wanted those to be part of `dev`.

After that, everything worked as expected.  It goes to show, don't take anything for granted.  I thought our pillars were working but as it turned out, they weren't.